# React native Nested navigatiion issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I save the stack navigator on the drawer navigator.

I have 2 problems.

1. The menu should not appear on the page when the application is opened.
2. The component name that I used during registration should not appear on the page I directed later.

I couldn't solve this issue. Can you help me?

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function Menu() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none" lazy={false}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Verify" component={VerifyScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Tarih" component={Datepicker} options={{
                animationEnabled: false,
            }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Otel" component={SearchedHotel} options={{
                animationEnabled: false,
            }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Bölge" component={Regions} options={{
                animationEnabled: false,
            }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Web" component={OtelScanner} options={{
                animationEnabled: false,
            }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

function Routing(props) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
            <ApplicationProvider mapping={mapping} theme={lightTheme}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Drawer.Navigator>
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
                        <Drawer.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} />
                    </Drawer.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </ApplicationProvider>
        </React.Fragment >
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `<NavigationContainer />` you should have a `<StackNavigator />` instead of `<DrawerNavigator />`

Example:
`NavigationContainer`

```xml
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Example: `Menu`

```xml
function Menu() {
    return (
       <Drawer.Navigator headerMode="none" lazy={false}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Verify" component={VerifyScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Tarih" component={Datepicker} options={{
                animationEnabled: false,
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Otel" component={SearchedHotel} options={{
                animationEnabled: false,
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Bölge" component={Regions} options={{
                animationEnabled: false,
            }} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Web" component={OtelScanner} options={{
                animationEnabled: false,
            }} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello my friend;
I tried this method. But first, Drawer doesn't work. Then the toggleDrawer openDrawer and closeDrawer methods don't work either.